# How can I save my progress?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm looking for how can I save my progress in GTA V. I've looked in menu (from pressing "start") then "GAME". I only see

- Replay Mission
- Replay Strangers and Freaks
- Load Game
- New Game

I activated the autosave but sometimes I want to save at a precise moment.

Comment: Note the default is for the game to auto save after you complete something.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Bring up your phone (<kbd>UP</kbd> on D-PAD or <kbd>↑</kbd> on Keyboard) and click the option "Quick Save":

[image]

You can also save by sleeping in a bed.

Comment: when can you bring up your phone? I don't seem to be able to do it during game play.

Comment: @frank - It's possible you can only save when not on a mission