# Saving a day's play on Grand Theft Auto

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Grand Theft Auto 5 refuses to save my game automatically.
After each play, on load it reverts to the start. I am not an experianced gamer. Please help as I cannot keep starting from the beginning.
Thanks

Comment: How far in the game have you made it when you stop playing?

Comment: Got past first two storylines-got money initially and then made it to the car.

Comment: Taken me about two hours of play to get this far (i know its not v good ) but as i said not experianced.Is that my problem -havent got far enough?

Comment: Hard to say, you should be far enough to save I think. Can you quick save from your phone, or save from the start menu? If not, then you have to at least get done with the first mission.

Comment: the phone wont come up as yet -keep pressing up button but nothing happens.

Comment: if its not a stupid question -how do u get up the start menu

Comment: Hit the start button on your controller. Save is somewhere in there, but it sounds like if the phone is not coming up, you may have to get farther in to the game to save it.

Comment: ok thanks will persevere-but taking me ages

Comment: Saved eventually after getting to Lamars house and sleeping-v frustrating to replay initial part of game so many times.

Comment: "Please help as I cannot keep starting from the beginning." - Can't, or won't?

Comment: You can be interested with http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/131573/1227

Comment: @PaulD.Waite ... either?

Comment: @alanstadler: you're not playing Candy Crush now, Alan! Welcome to big school!

Comment: @Robotnik: that is exactly the sort of answer I'd expect from an evil genius.

Answer (score 2):

There's three ways to save the game.
You can save through the start menu.
You can save at a safe house if you have one unlocked.
The game should autosave after completing a mission, as long as you don't have autosave turned off.

Answer (score 1):

> Grand Theft Auto 5 refuses to save my game automatically.

You can head down to `Pause Menu > Settings > Saving/Saving and Startup` and check that Autosave is enabled.

PS3 & Xbox 360:

[image: Autosave on PS3]

PS4, Xbox One and PC:

[image: Autosave on PC]

Even if the auto save didn't work, you can quick save after a mission by using the phone:

[image: Quick save on Franklin's phone]

Or by sleeping on one of the beds:

[image: Franklin's bed on his aunt house.]

After that you will have to choose a save space, you can either create a new one or overwrite an existing save:

[image: The save game screen with 10 used slots of 15.]

After that the current game state will be saved and the progress should stay intact, but remember to save the game constantly!